# For loop in two dimensional array

Tags: c++, arrays

When trying to compile code g++ gives me this error: 'array must be initialized with a brace-enclosed initializer'

```
#include<iostream>

int main(){
    int coordinates[3][2]={{1,2},
                           {5,2},
                           {5,9}};
    for(int coordinate[2]:coordinates){
        std::cout<<coordinate[0]+coordinate[1];
    };
    return 0;
};
```

Comment: your for() loop isn't correct. What are you exactly trying to print?

Comment: I am trying to make a chess game and the coordinates array are the possible movements this for loop is to higlight the board tiles where are a possible movement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I can clearly see a problem in your code.

In loop, type is not plain int, but int*. You have two options, either use int* or auto

Your final code should look line

```
int main(){
    int coordinates[3][2]=
    {
        {1,2},
        {5,2},
        {5,9}
    };

    // You can use either int* or auto.
    // I personally prefer auto
    // as it's more cleaner.
    //
    // for(int *coordinate :coordinates){


    for(auto coordinate:coordinates){
        std::cout<<coordinate[0]+coordinate[1];
    };
    return 0;
};
```

Comment: @RobertoJaimes, you are welcome. glad it worked for you.